# If $LL^T = (DC)(DC)^T$, where $L,D,C$ are matrices, does $L = DC$?

Tags: linear-algebra, cholesky-decomposition

The variance-covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is related to the correlation matrix $\varrho$ by the equation

$\Sigma = D \varrho D$, where $D = \sqrt{\text{diag}(\Sigma)}$

Now consider the Cholesky decomposition of $\Sigma$ and $\varrho$, where $\Sigma=LL^T$ and $\varrho = CC^T$.

I want to show that the Cholesky decompositions of these are related by $L = DC$. How do I do this?

This is how far I got:

$\Sigma = D \varrho D \implies LL^T = DCC^TD$

$\implies LL^T = DCC^TD^T$, because $D= D^T$ since it is a diagonal (and thus symmetric) matrix.

$\implies LL^T = DC(DC)^T$

It looks like I am very nearly done. Is it possible to "square root" both sides and get $L = DC$?

Comment: Basically you're asking this: If $A,B$ are two square matrixes such that $AA^T=BB^T$ then do we have $A=B$? The answer is no. Consider when $A$ is given and $B=AQ$ where $Q$ is orthogonal.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. However, I am asking about the particular case where $L$ and $C$ are lower triangular matrices (they are components of the Cholesky decompositions), and $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: I assume we are dealing with invertible matrices -- Answering your title question: with the standard constraint that the diagonal is all positive, the Choleksy decomposition is unique.  $DC$ is lower triangular, so if you check the diagonal and its positive then it must $=L$.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. How did you use the fact that the Cholesky decomposition is unique to derive $L = DC$?

Comment: Do you know the proof of why Cholesky is unique?  It's worth learning and answers your question